# Is this model secure for offline storage?

Tags: javascript, encryption, local-storage

I'm making interface based on 3rd party api. My app works as data analyzer, and to do that i need to download lots of data and this data keeps updating.

But api has limits, and i can't have user download entire set of data at each session. That would not scale.

So i'm thinking simplest way is to let user sync when he wish to, and save the data in local storage.

However, i don't want any user on that computer to have access to all data.

Therefore, i've come up with this scheme that will let the data be safe.

1. send javascript via https.
2. using js do oauth and retrieves data from api servers.
3. get opensource library like cryptojs also using https.
4. Encrypts data using user's (secret key + salt) and then save both in storage. So even if someone sees it then he can't understand it.
5. Then at every new session take stored salt and secret key to match hash(es) and get that data. Or simply start new auth process from step 2.
6. if hashed data is older than 30 days delete it. (which could mean user no longer uses the computer or has forgotten password, either way data should be outdated and will need to be resynced by downloading all again)

Comment: Where are salt and secret key stored?

Comment: local storage... so even if they can be looked at it should be very difficult.Just like if database on server is hacked, it'd take hacker looong time to make rainbow table.. But i guess salt benefit is halved. In server setting, salt provides length with uniqueness but here it just provide length. At least that's my theory

Comment: Wrt salt+RT (other issues aside): as long as the salt is a large nonce the RT is ineffective and might as well try BF. BF is covered by using a *slower* hash/encryption.

Comment: If the salt and secret key are stored locally, then encrypting the data in the local storage only provides some obscuration of the data, not real security.  In fact, anyone can just grab your local JS code and run it locally to get at the data without having any credentials.  Now, if the secret key was stored on the server and only retrieved after authentication with the server, that would provide some actual security because server authentication would be required before being able to decrypt the data.  Important to make sure you know the difference between obfuscation and security.

Comment: sorry i meant secret key, the password, isn't stored and doesn't need to be stored, but hash of password+salt and salt is stored. And data is encrypted with the password. So if user inputs the password only then it can be decrypted. One can easily get Js code and all data but since he doesn't know they password but only has hash of it he would need to find the password, which should be very hard due to lengthy salt. And once someone enters password then data will be decrypted.

Comment: in theory it should be possible to not even store hash of password, and just take user's input and encrypt all data using it. But then when decrypting i think it will make application slow if i have to encrypt lots of data only to find it was wrong. So hash and salt serve as check if password is right, and if it's right then it's used for decrypting data.